# convert an array to list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, k-means

my code is :
`km = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1,verbose=0)
    predict=[]

    predict.append(km.fit_predict(matrix))`
the result is :[array([0,0,1,1,0])]

then I want to zip this result by list of string
the result of zip is a list with one member because it assume**[array([0,0,1,1,0])]** as a list that has one member.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is returning a list with one array in it.  So, you should be able to zip it with:

```
zip(list_of_strings, result[0])
```

Comment: I got the following error when I used tolist() in python 2.7 **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist'**

Comment: I should write predict[0] to have a list

Comment: The function is returning a list that contains a single array.  So, yes, you should be able to iterate over the array (in the zip) by using predict[0].